# split line and keep first few columns with each new line

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new line every time a comma occurs but keep the first few columns with the new line.  For clarity:

```
A    B    C,    D,
E    F    Z
G    H    I,   J,
```

Should look like at the end:

```
A    B    C
A    B    D
E    F    Z
G    H    I
G    H    J
```

I am new to python but I am trying, so I understand split would be best for me, but I have no idea how to keep the first few columns in (there are actually 7 columns to keep) and for each appearance of comma, create a new line with the first 7 columns still there

So far I tried :

```
lines = df.split(",")
for column in lines:
    print(column)
```

which would give me:

```
A    B    C
D
E    F    Z
G    H    I
J
```

which is not much I know, but it is a start :)

Comment: Can you help us understand what column is here (Context) ?

Comment: Just each column after the split (not sure I explain well)

Comment: Does the whole df have 3 columns? Does it have to generalize?

Comment: What is the original structure?? Is it a df? Is it a single column?

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
example = 'A\tB\tC,\tD,\nE\tF\tZ\nG\tH\tI,\tJ,'

lines = example.split('\n')
new_text = ''
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip(',').split('\t')
    new_lines = [[]]
    index = 0
    for element in line:
        if ',' in element:
            new_lines.append(copy.deepcopy(new_lines[index]))
            new_lines[index].append(element.rstrip(','))
            index += 1
        else:
            new_lines[index].append(element)

    for new_line in new_lines:
        new_text += '\t'.join(new_line)+'\n'

print(new_text)
```

This gives

```
A   B   C
A   B   D
E   F   Z
G   H   I
G   H   J
```

Comment: Thanks, this is way more complex than I expected it :) but it only gives me  the last two lines, perhaps I am doing something wrong!